# Partition and Riemann-Stieltjes integration

Tags: solution-verification, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, stieltjes-integral

> Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded on $[a , b]$ and $g \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a ,b]$. Also $P$ is an arbitrary partition. If $f\le g$ and $\alpha$ is increasing on $[a , b]$ determine whether the following propositions are true or false:
> $1.$ $L(P,f,\alpha) \le \int_a^b gd\alpha$
> $2.$ $U(P,f,\alpha) \le \int_a^b gd\alpha$

**My try:** I think the first one is true since $$f\le g \implies \int_a^b fd\alpha \le \int_a^b gd\alpha \\ L(P,f,\alpha)\le \int_a^b fd\alpha \implies L(P,f,\alpha)\le \int_a^b gd\alpha$$
The second proposition is wrong. Let $f=g =x$ and $a = 0,b =2, P = \{0 ,1,2\}$. Then $U(P,f,\alpha) = 3$ and $\int_a^b gd\alpha = 2$. Clearly $3 \not \le 2$, so this is false.

Are my answers correct and precise?

Comment: For (2) your counterexample is correct. Just add that $\alpha(x) = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) your approach is not adequate, as it is possible that $f \leqslant g$ but $f \not\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$. This occurs when $f$ and $\alpha$ are both discontinuous at a point in $[a,b]$ from the right or left.

A simple argument is

$$L(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{j=1}^n \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x) \cdot (\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})) \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}g(x) \cdot (\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1}))\\ \leqslant \int_a^b g \, d\alpha $$